# Where can I find a formal definition of the elasticsearch DSL?

Tags: elasticsearch

The elasticseach documentation is very informal. For example, [Filtered Query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filtered-query.html) 
does not specify if the "query" or the "filter" part is required. There is a comment under "query" that says `query definition`, but there is no further explanation what this is supposed to mean. To interpret the documentation, a lot of guesswork is needed to figure out what is legal.

Where can I find a formal definition of the elasticseach DSL?

Answer (score 1):

The first `query` is an option of the `_search` endpoint where you can specify your query, however complex it may be.

The second `query` is a parameter of the `match` query containing the terms to be searched for. Agreed, it could have been called `value` or `input` or `whatever`. There's nothing recursive about it and I admit it can throw off newcomers, but it's like being able to declare an `int` variable outside of a function and inside of it. There are no best practices telling that a keyword should only be used once in a single specific context within a given language.

Anyway, I've been playing with the DSL for 13+ years but I agree that a specification of the DSL is long overdue. However, if we reuse the sample query you gave and decide to use the OR operator instead of the AND one, we can write it as follows in [short form](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html#query-dsl-match-query-short-ex) because we use all the defaults parameters or the `match` query:

```
GET books/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "author": "Joshua Schildt"
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, there's no more `query` and the `author` parameters is directly assigned the searched terms and not a JSON hash with the query parameters. This flexibility makes it difficult to come up with a clear DSL specification since there are many different ways to write a query depending on how you want to configure it.

There is indeed a TypeScript "specification" of all the operations and data types that can be exchanged between a client and en Elasticsearch server and you can find it in the [`elastic/elasticsearch-specification`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-specification) Github repo, and also precisely, for the [`match` query](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-specification/blob/main/specification/_types/query_dsl/fulltext.ts#L283), where all the possible parameters are described.

On line 282, we can even see that the `MatchQuery` is annotated with `@shortcut_property query` meaning that the whole JSON structure can be replaced with the just the value of the `query` parameter as we saw earlier.

Also worth noting, you can find an [OpenAI specification](https://cloud.elastic.co/api/v1/api-docs/spec.json) for all the operations supported by Elasticsearch REST APIs.

Also worth noting that in version 8.11 that will be released any day now, a new piped language called [ES|QL](https://www.elastic.co/blog/esql-elasticsearch-piped-query-language) will be released and [the documentation of the language](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.11/esql-language.html) should be much more to your liking as it's a more "formal" language and comes with in-app documentation.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks. In fact the book (ES in Action, 2nd ed.) explains at that point precisely what you say: that by default "OR" applies in a query --> match query, so it is showing how to use "AND" in contrast. I don't really understand what a "TypeScript" spec is and to be honest am baffled by that page and the links from it.

Comment: Also, I've been pondering what you say about DSL's flexibility (ultimately, flexibility of syntax). But this can't be infinite, and in fact there's a place it is set in stone (for a given version of ES): the source code. What is needed is a set of laws (aka specifications), simply translating what the source code says into something more immediately able to be used as a pure reference. At the moment I'm anticipating having to investigate all the ins and outs of the source code and its architecture. This shouldn't be needed.

Comment: [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) is a better version of JavaScript with strong typing. That language can also be used for specifying type hierarchies and the reason it's been used for specifying the Elasticsearch REST API and query DSL is because it's fully deterministic and precise, i.e. there's no unknown. Also that specification can be and is used for automatically generating client libraries and all the set of classes used by them to interact with the server. It's used for generating code, but it could also be used for generating documentation.

Comment: The [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index.html) (not the definitive guide you reference and which is listed in the legacy outdated documentation) is pretty well written and can be used as reference, but, yes, you have to go read it somehow. There's absolutely no need to go into the source code in order to learn how to build DSL queries.

Comment: Thanks again. Yes, I know about the official documentation. My experience in the past of trying to learn from this has been very bad. But actually just looking now at the section on QueryDSL it's actually pretty good, and there is more of it than I thought. Is it in fact *comprehensive* in your opinion? I looked again at that page on the TypeScript specification: sorry, but I'd need an explanatory guide to understand what I'm even looking at there... "Make targets" ... "Validate the specification"... what is all this? Still totally baffled.

Comment: Having worked with Elasticsearch for the past 13 years, I can tell that the official query DSL documentation has improved by magnitudes and I find it pretty good (yes comprehensive) and improving on every new version. I might have initially misunderstood what you were looking for. I thought you were in need of something more "formal" and that's how I came with their specification, but I understand now that it's not what you're looking for, so you can disregard that part, it's not for you.

Comment: @mikerodent I just amended my answer with some updates as a new and more "formal" querying language is going to be released any day now.

Comment: Thanks... that looks very interesting. I'm quite happy to give you the bounty but I think I might leave it for a day or two just to see what anyone else might have to say.

Comment: No problem, happy to help! And 8.11 just got released minutes ago, so it's available for you to try out

Answer (score -1):

I found [Elasticsearch Query DSL documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl.html) to be quite comprehensive.

I guess in the example you highlight, it is a bit tricky. Filtered Query is a chain to the results of another query.

The `query definition` and `filter definition` of Filtered query maps to [queries](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-queries.html) and [filters](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filters.html) section of the Query DSL (probably not obvious). You could use any of the queries (match etc.) and any of the filter (exists etc) in the filtered query payload.

Comment: This still does not answer the question if both parts are required or optional. If I write a query by hand, that is not a problem. But if the query is generated, and the ```fiter``` part is empty, can I still use a Filtered Query or do I have to drop the Filtered Query "wrapper" and only use the Query part.